# mousehold event while doing mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousemove

I've downloaded a JQuery plugin for a mousehold event.

http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/

I have this div that calls for mousemove event:

```
div.addEventListener('mousemove',function() {
//things
});
```

whenever I call the mousehold event like this:

```
var value = 0;
$(div).mousehold(function() {
value += 20;
$(div).html(value);
});
```

it would work. But if I start moving (thus, calling the mousemove event) while onmousehold, the value does not increase anymore, meaning, it stopped calling the mousehold event even if I got my left click still on hold.

How can I make it happen that when I do a mousemove, the mousehold event still works? tnx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking (at least, what I think you're asking), is simple enough with some basic logic.

By binding the mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup and setting a flag for the "down" state of the mouse, this can easily be done: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phix/WtaKJ/)

Comment: try using the jquery plugin I posted. I already tried your solution before I posted here. The problem is that when a new event has been called, the mousehold event gets canceled. The difference between your solution and the solution im looking for is that the incremenation of the value is made in the mousemove event but the incrementation that I want is to happen in the mousehold event. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the event object like so:

```js
div.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {

  // `event.buttons` gets the state of the mouse buttons
  // 0 = not pressed, 1 = left click pressed, 2 = right click pressed
  if (event.buttons === 1) {
    value += 20;
  }

});
```